# Using CardLayout in NetBeans GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am using the NetBeans 7.2.1 GUI Builder. I could do all of this by hand. Instead, I am using my current project to learn how this tool works so that I can make an informed decision of when to use it in the futre (if at all).

Now with help of archived questions here, I have figured out how to change the LayoutManager to a CardLayout. I have also added three JPanels to the layout (although, there seems to be a bug...maybe a question about that later). The first JPanel displayed by the CardLayout will have two buttons. Each button will cause the CardLayout to display one of the other two JPanels. To do this, I found that I can use [`CardLayout#show(Container, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29).

I need to know what the value of the String is for each JPanel. Doing some further research, I found that NetBeans generates a line of code such as

```
getContentPane().add(addCardsPanel, "card2");
```

So I can use "card2" to show addCardsPanel. It would be convenient to use a more applicable String. Will NetBeans allow me to set this identifying String to whatever value I wish? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: If it doesn't, you can use the component's `getName()`/`setName()`.

Comment: FWIW, I recommend abandoning Netbeans' GUI builder. I did it for my most recent project, and I'm using much fewer lines of code with more flexibility. Not to mention there's no battles with a read-only chunk of code.

Comment: @gobernador I certainly realize some of the pros and cons. This is one reason I am using it for my current project. In particular, I want to get a more concrete feel for the differences. (See the first paragraph in my question.) Very likely I will go back to coding everything by hand.

Comment: I understand. Completely your choice, this is just my $0.02

Comment: @gobernador Thanks! Too bad that's not enough for coffee ;-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Navigator` window select the panel you want.

In the `Properties` window scroll down to the `Layout` group.  You'll see a `Card Name` property.  Knock your self out ;)